# Jquery monthpicker giving output as NaN-undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement Monthpicker, but the whole calendar is showing. I want only the month and year as input, not the entire calendar. And moreover, after selecting the date from the calendar which is show, the input in the text box is displaying as **Undefined-NaN**. The existing code is as follows:

```
$('#newBatchDate').datepicker({
  showOtherMonths: true,
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "images/calender.png",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  buttonText: "Date"
});
```

How do I modify this code to implement monthpicker?

Answer (score 0):

To get a month selection, you have to modify the _generateHTML function of the datepicker object.

```js
$.extend($.datepicker, {
  _generateDaysHTML: $.datepicker._generateHTML,
  _generateMonthsHTML: function(inst) {
    /*  
      Generate HTML for monthpicking
      -> draw each month of the current year
      -> link to first day of each month
    */
  },
  _generateHTML: function(inst) {
    if ( inst.settings.monthPicker ) {
      return this._generateMonthsHTML(inst);
    } else {
      return this._generateDaysHTML(inst);
    }
  }
});
```

To have some defaults, create a monthpicker fn:

```js
$.fn.monthpicker = function(options) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var altField = $this.next();
    altField.on('focus', function() { $this.datepicker('show') });
    var settings = {
      monthPicker: true,
      stepMonths: 12,
      changeMonth: false,
      altField: altField,
      altFormat: 'M yy' }
    $.extend(settings, options);
    $this.datepicker(settings);
  });
}
```

This fn is using a hidden field as the primary date field (value is always the 1th of the selected month) and a text field (via altField) to display the selected month.

```html
<input class="js-monthpicker" type="hidden"><input type="text">
```

Initialize it...

```js
$('.js-monthpicker').monthpicker();
```

You may want to check the source [here](https://github.com/tlemens/jquery-ui-monthpicker).

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.